# Wavelet correlation using rolling window

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, wavelet, rollapply

I have 3 time series which I can apply the wavelet transform to using a rolling window. The rolling window takes a single time series of length 200 and applies the `waveslim::modwt` function to it over the first 30 samples. This outputs 5 lists of which I am only interested in (d1,d2,d3,d4) and these each have a length of 30. A simple example can be found here:

```
library(waveslim)
J <- 4 #no. of levels in decomposition
data(ar1)
ar1.modwt <- modwt(ar1, "la8", J)
```

@G. Grothendieck has kindly provided a neat piece of code for the rolling window approach for a single time series [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655879/using-rollapply-to-output-to-lists-of-lists).

The rolling window increments by 1 and we go again, producing another 5 lists of which I only care for d1->d4 and so on and so on until the full length of the time series had been rolled over.

The next step is to apply the `waveslim::brick.wall` function to the output of the rolling window lists. The `brick.wall` function looks at the output of `modwt` for the first window across the 4 levels and replaces some of the values with `NA`s.

I believe I have covered this by modifying @G. Grothendieck answer using the following approach, I hope I am right:

```
modwt2 <- function(...) unlist(head(brick.wall(modwt(...)), 4))
rollr <- rollapplyr(ar1, 30, FUN = modwt2, wf = "la8", n.levels = 4, boundary = "periodic")
L <- lapply(1:nrow(rollr), function(i) matrix(rollr[i,], , 4))
```

The final piece is to construct correlation matrices for the outputs of the `brick.wall` function which is `L` above over the 4 levels of interest.

There is a function called `waveslim::wave.correlation` which takes two `brick.wall` outputs X and Y and computes the `wave.correlation` over the various levels.

```
library(waveslim)
data(exchange)
returns <- diff(log(as.matrix(exchange)))
returns <- ts(returns, start=1970, freq=12)
wf <- "la8"
J <- 4
demusd.modwt <- modwt(returns[,"DEM.USD"], wf, J)
demusd.modwt.bw <- brick.wall(demusd.modwt, wf)
jpyusd.modwt <- modwt(returns[,"JPY.USD"], wf, J)
jpyusd.modwt.bw <- brick.wall(jpyusd.modwt, wf)
returns.modwt.cor <- wave.correlation(demusd.modwt.bw, jpyusd.modwt.bw,
                                      N = dim(returns)[1])
```

I wish to expand on this and compute the full correlation matrix for my 3 time series. Please note that the example above with exchange rates does not use the rolling window approach as it uses the full length of the time series which I would like to now do and it also produces a single value for the correlation between two time series. It does not construct the full correlation matrix which I need as I am interested in the eigenvalues of these correlation matrices over time.

So in summary:

1. Take 3 time series
2. Apply `modwt` function using rolling window
3. Apply `brick.wall` function to each output of the rolling window in 2 above
4. Create full 3x3 correlation matrix for the 4 levels using outputs of 3 above over time

Comment: I don't get it, you almost have everything and just need to apply/modify `wave.correlation` for 3 time series?

Comment: @PoGibas it's not that simple, well at least not in my head.Yes I have part 1 and 2 and I need to create the 3rd but I am not a strong programmer and working with lists is difficult for me, I don't have any experience working with them. If you have any input I would be delighted to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together the pieces you give in your question:

**1) Create 3 time series**

```
set.seed(1)
s <- replicate(3, rnorm(200), simplify = FALSE)
```

**2) & 3) Apply `modwt` and `brick.wall` with rolling window**

```
modwt2 <- function(...) unlist(head(brick.wall(modwt(...), wf = "la8"), 4))

rollr <- lapply(s, function(x) rollapplyr(x, 30, FUN = modwt2, wf = "la8", 
                                          n.levels = 4, boundary = "periodic"))

L <- lapply(rollr, function(x) lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) matrix(x[i,], , 4)))

res <- lapply(L, function(y) lapply(y, function(x) as.list(as.data.frame(x))))
```

**4) Create correlation matrices**

```
create_4mat <- function(w) {
  # create four 3*3 correlation matrices (one for each level) for window w
  M <- replicate(4, matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3), simplify = FALSE)
  for (k in 1:4) {
    for (i in 1:3) {
      for (j in (i:3)[-1]) {
        M[[k]][i, j] = wave.correlation(res[[i]][[w]], res[[j]][[w]], N=30)[k, 1]
      }
    }
    M[[k]] <- M[[k]] + t(M[[k]]) + diag(1, 3, 3)
  }
  M
}

output <- lapply(1:171, create_4mat)
```

`output` is a list of 171 lists of 4 correlations matrices.

For instance, `output[[28]][[2]]` is the correlation matrix for `d2` in the 28th window:

```
output[[28]][[2]]
#            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# [1,]  1.0000000 -0.1740320 0.2292872
# [2,] -0.1740320  1.0000000 0.6046918
# [3,]  0.2292872  0.6046918 1.0000000
```

**Edit: Eigenvalues (as requested in comment)**

For `d1`:

```
eigenvalues1 <- lapply(output, function(x) eigen(x[[1]], symmetric = TRUE, 
                                                 only.values = TRUE)$values)
```

Similarly for `d2`. Note that for `d3` and `d4` all correlation matrices are filled with missing values.

Comment: thanks you very much for this, this is a massive help. One last piece now that I have "output" is how can I use the apply function and eigen function to calculate the eigenvalues for each of the levels i.e. d1->d4?